# What is the purpose of the arrow $\leftarrow$ in this formula?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, notation, value-functions

What is the purpose of the arrow $\leftarrow$ in the formula below?

$$V(S_t) \leftarrow V(S_t) + \alpha \left[ G_t - V(S_t) \right]$$

I presume it's not the same as 'equals'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is an iterative function. It means the current $V(S_t)$ **is** the sum of the previous plus some adjustment. The arrow is like an **assignment**.

In code, you would do

```
vst = vst + alpha * (gt - vst)
```

So `vst` will be overwritten.